# VB.Net Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vb.net

Team.. I have read a number of posts and still in need of guidance please.
I have a Weighing Program VB.2017 that I have written from Scratch instead of porting the VB6 version but stumbling on a Hand Scanner issue. (OnComm not supported in VB.Net)

This Code will read the input (Printed Barcode using a serial handheld barcode scanner - Motorola Symbol) but I'm trying to get a SUB executed when the Barcode Scanner button is pressed. It simply reads off a Barcode and will populate a text box.

Working code that does capture the barcode (after defining the scanner properties and opens the com port. But Can not work out how to execute a Sub when the button is pressed on the scanner.

```
            MyCOMPortScanner.Open()

        _continue = True

        Do
            Dim Incoming As String = MyCOMPortScanner.ReadLine()
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                returnStr = Incoming
            End If
        Loop

    Catch ex As IOException
        Showmessage(ex.Message & " ComOpen IO")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Showmessage(ex.Message & " ComOpen EX")
```

Code not working unless I have the cursor in a textbox and only keyboard input not scanner. I have KeyPreview set to true.

I've tried both KeyPress & also KeyDown.

```
Private Sub Weighing_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

    Private Sub Weighing_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
```

Again the above 2 work but only for the keyboard and not recognising the trigger press of the barcode scanner.

Sorry Team.. Still at a loss as I simply don't understand.. I tried so many different ways around defining the event like the keydown which works. but still at a loss sorry.

```
    Private Sub Weighing_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

End Sub
'Public Event KeyDown As KeyEventHandler
'Public Event GetSerialData As KeyEventHandler
'Public Event GetSerialData As GetSerialDataEventHandler
Public Event GetSerialData(sender As Object, e As GetSerialDataEventHandler)

Private Sub GetSerialData(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.GetSerial

End Sub

'Private Sub GetSerial(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.GetSerialEventArgs) Handles Me.GetSerial
'End Sub

Public Sub GetSerial()

End Sub
```

Please help as Im going nuts reading so many posts and not getting anywhere. My code is over 1k lines and this is the only outstanding issue

Comment: I assume it should not be the System.Windows.Forms... but should be the IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs

Answer (score 0):

I think that catching the textbox changed event suffice to your needs.

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox.TextChanged
   Try
      ' Do something
   Catch
      ' Catch something
   End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Alessandro thankyou for the feedback.. The issue is that the scanner does not relate to a textbox. The system is made around a touch screen with the option of using the handscanner to read barcodes. When I press the trigger of the barcode scanner, I need it to perform a routine (Sub) to see what has been read. Pressing the trigger currently does not call the event. Only if I have my cursor in a textbox and press a key it calls that routine.

Comment: Just a update.. This code is working regardless of where the cursor is currently positioned on the screen if you press any key. It still does not fire if the trigger on the barcode scanner is depressed.     Private Sub Weighing_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

Comment: Just use an textbox having property visible=false, and scan the barcode into it.

Comment: Alessandro..Again thankyou. How do I scan the Barcode into it. I must be missing the obvious sorry. I can't get my head around how pulling the scanner trigger can execute this code. I even tried using this to listen for the trigger execution.         Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                         ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
                                         Handles serialport1.DataReceived

Comment: I did as you mentioned but that code does not get executed because the scanner does not capture anything and therefore I can not move the data to the TextBox. The issue remains how can I recognise the trigger of the scanner is pulled..?

Comment: A barcode scanner is a keyboard. Just move the cursor into the textbox, by using a GotFocus or Select() method and make sure it stays there or goes back there whenever a keypress event is recorded. This is just an idea, depending on the actual content of your form. And you can't just press the trigger on the barcode. You need to scan a real barcode for this to work. Just grab something on your desk with a barcode on it. You probably can't detect a trigger on a bardcode scanner unless you have got a dll from the barcode scanner producer which makes a "trigger pressed event" available

Comment: Alessandro.. I do have a barcode for testing that I printed. The first bit of code above "MyCOMPortScanner.Open()" sets the comm port values and also if I put a break point in at the "Dim Incoming As String = MyCOMPortScanner.ReadLine()" and scan the printed barcode it is capturing the barcode value. Once it drops out of that SUB I then need it to recognise if another barcode is scanned and perform a different SUB that strips the barcode data.My old VB6 project uses the same scanner but uses the old OnComm logic. No dll was needed as its just reading serial data. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: it doesn't. I'm confused. Is it a serial device? Or is it a USB device? The sub captures one barcode, and then it doesn't capture any further barcode? Are you closing the port after first scan, or are you not opening the port? Or is it the port already opened when you try to open it once again, and you end up in the catch?

Comment: It is a serial Barcode Scanner. Agree the inital Sub does just get the first barcode scanned which proves it can communicate with the scanner. The Port is staying open as per the WATCH list in dbugging. Not being closed. I just need a method of catching when the next barcode is scanned without having the cursor in any particular position on the screen. The Private Sub Weighing_KeyDown works if a key is pressed but never when the barcode is scanned.

Comment: The datareceived event is what you are looking for, and you already mentioned it , so it must work. If it doesn't, you are probably missing to add the appropriate handler in the code.

Comment: Thank you Alessandro.. needed a couple of days away from this to recharge... I shall pursue this approach.. I'm not very familar with the handles.. I educate myself now thankyou

Answer (score 0):

OMG.. Sorry for wasting everyone's time and Alessandro prompts.
When I defined the port and did my initial read which worked I was simply using a different PortName (MyCOMPortScanner) instead of SerialPort1.
Now when I press the trigger on the scanner it now enters the code.